# How to get this panel as an inner class to work?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

As you guys can see I'm having trouble in adding the panel into the frame...I know it might be something easy...but I cant see it...if you guys can point me to the right direction :)

```
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.*;

/**
 *
 * @author Doohickey
 */
public class StudentInfo {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    private String firstName, lastName;
    private String birthday, studentID;
    private String pictureFileLocation;
    private char gender;
    private List<String> enrolledPapers;

    public StudentInfo(String studentID){
        this.studentID = studentID;
    }

    public StudentInfo(String studentID, String firstName, String lastName,
            String birthday, char gender){

        this.studentID = studentID;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.birthday = birthday;
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    public void addPaper(String paper){
        enrolledPapers.add(paper);
    }

    public List<String> getEnrolledPapers(){
        return enrolledPapers;
    }

    public void setPictureFromFileName(String fileName){
        pictureFileLocation = fileName;
    }

    public String getPictureFileName(){
        return pictureFileLocation;
    }

    public String getFirstName(){
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName(){
        return lastName;
    }

    public String getBirthday(){
        return birthday;
    }

    public String getStudentID(){
        return studentID;
    }

    public char getGender(){
        return gender;
    }

    public JComponent getStudentPanel(){
        return null; 
    }

    public class StudentPanel extends JPanel{
        public StudentPanel(){

            JTextField stFirstName = new JTextField("First name: "+firstName);
            JTextField stLastName = new JTextField("Last name: "+ lastName);
            JComboBox stBirth = new JComboBox();
            JRadioButton stGender = new JRadioButton();
            JPanel stPanel = new JPanel();

            stPanel.add(stFirstName);
            stPanel.add(stLastName);
            stPanel.add(stBirth);
            stPanel.add(stGender);

            add(stPanel);
        }     
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Student info");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(new StudentPanel());
        frame.pack();                                      //pack frame
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your trying to create a non-static class from a static context.

Try and make you inner panel static...

```
public static class StudentPanel extends JPanel {
```

Unless this is just some testing, I would avoid mixing your classes in the is way.  You're not adding any value to the `StudentInfo` info class

Comment: doesn't have any other way to do it?
because if I do that the variables in there wont work

Comment: Rather then the `StudentPanel` relying on the `StudentInfo` directly, the `StudentInfo` should be PASSED to the `StudentPanel`.  This makes `StudentPanel` re-usable